# Changing the API source in Firefox/Chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I'm debugging on my local host but want to change the default API url from https://dev.domainname.com/api/ to https://devtwo.domainname.com/api/. I know there is a way to force it by entering something into the console, but I can't remember what it is. I'd like to have the command for both Firefox and Chrome.

Please forgive my ignorance in using the proper language or explanation...I'm learning!

Answer (score 0):

At the Web console with the page opened (can be the local development server created, or a website Webapp like dev.domainname.com), use next to setup a different REST Service URL:

```
localStorage["NameApp/config"] = '{"siteUrl":"http://devtwo.domainname.com"}';
```

To restore it, and left the App/Webapp use the default URL just:
    delete localStorage["NameApp/config"]